# How to check for null values before Converting a comma Separated string to Generic List

Tags: c#, linq

I want to convert from a comma separated string value to a Generic List of Strings.  I would like to do that without using some method.

I am using the following code below but this gives me an implicit conversion error.

```
List<string> lstTags = (string.IsNullOrEmpty(f.TagName) ? new List<string>():
 (new List<string>(f.TagName.Split(',')));
```

Comment: Why not break this up into multiple lines?  It would be easier to debug, easier on the next dev who looks at it, and probably just as fast to execute if not faster.

Comment: Calling `ToString()` on the `List<string>` is probably not what you want to be doing...

Comment: @DanPichelman Always remember - the person who replaces you has a good chance of being a psycho axe murder.  You don't want to set him off.  "[Always code as if the person who ends up maintaining your code is a violent psychopath who knows where you live.](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2008/06/coding-for-violent-psychopaths.html)"

Comment: @Telastyn I apologize.  That was left there from my previous attempts at correcting my issue.  I just edited it. Thanks!

Comment: @ENC0D3D - then at quick glance there's nothing _syntactically_ wrong with that code, assuming `TagName` is a `string`.

Answer (score 7):

If you add "using System.Linq;", you could use .ToList() to turn the string array that .Split() returns into a List.

```
List<string> lstTags = (String.IsNullOrEmpty(f.TagName) ? new List<string>() :
    f.TagName.Split(',').ToList());
```

Or, if you didn't mind the small inefficiency of calling .Split() and .ToList() when f.TagName is null, then you could use the null-coalescing operator (??):

```
List<string> lstTags = (f.TagName ?? "").Split(',').ToList();
```

Answer (score 2):

First, it seems like you are trying to instantiate a List object with a constructor that takes in a string[] returned from Split().  List<> constructors take either IEnumerables or ints to determine size, but there is no C# List<> constructor that takes in a string[].

Second, you for some reason have a ToString() method attached to your List<> reference.  I believe this will return a hexadecimal string for your memory location.

Instead of this complicated string, try doing something like this:

```
List<string> lstTags = new List<string>():
if(!(string.IsNullOrEmpty(f.TagName))
    lstTags.AddRange(f.TagName.Split(',');
```

AddRange() adds an array of objects returned from a statement.

Comment: AddRange!  How Awesome!  Hadn't heard of this nugget!